# Do you know any video chat room providers with WebAPI?

Tags: video, chat, video-conferencing

I want to be able to programmatically create a video chat room and send its link to a customer, so he will be able to chat with an employee. I've been looking for a provider of such service but didn't find much.

My requirements:

- WebAPI
- No need of installing a client, users just need a web browser
- Pay as You go

Do you know and can recommend any such provider ?

Kind regards